# Ext js form validator validate with unique names

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs, sencha-touch

I have Ext Form :

```
Ext.define('Count.view.AddJListForm', {
    extend      : 'Ext.form.Panel',
    controller  : 'List',
    xtype       : 'add-list',
    name        : 'addListForm',
    cls         : 'addFormToolbar',
    width       : '100%',
    height      : '100%',
    layout      : 'hbox', 
    fullscreen  : true,
    scrollable  : true,
    items       : 
        [
            {
                 xtype        : 'titlebar',
                 title        : 'Add New  Name',
                 docked       : 'top',
            },
            {
                xtype       : 'formpanel',
                fullscreen  : true,
                 items      : 
                     [
                         {
                             xtype      : 'hiddenfield',
                             name       : 'id'
                         },
                         {
                            xtype       : 'textfield',
                            name        : 'ListName',
                            maxLength   : 100,
                            label       : 'List name',
                            labelAlign  : 'top',
                            required    : true

                         },
                         {
                            xtype       : 'numberfield',
                            name        : 'Count',
                            maxLength   : 10,
                            label       : 'Count',
                            labelAlign  : 'top',
                            required    : true
                         },

                      ]
            },
            {
                xtype         : 'toolbar',
                ui            : 'plain',
                docked        : 'bottom',
                items         :
                    [
                        {
                            xtype   : 'spacer'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype   : 'button',
                            text    : 'CANCEL',
                            name    : 'closeAddListFormView',
                        },
                        {
                            xtype   : 'button',
                            text    : 'SAVE',
                            name    : 'formSave',
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ]
});
```

Controller function :
In this function to get the form values and stored into Database:

```
Ext.define('Count.view.ListController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.JapaList',
control: {
    'button[name=formSave]':    {
        tap     : 'saveListData'
    }
}
```

// File save function

```
 saveListData : function(button, record)
 {
    var form            = button.up('formpanel');
    var values          = form.getValues();
    var BgImage         = '';
    var audioFile       = '';    

    if(form.validate())
    {
       var ListName = values.ListName;
       var Count    = values.Count;
       callBackSaveData var table       = JapaCount.Db.tblJapaList;
        toDbArray['ListName']   = ListName;
        toDbArray['Count']      = Count;
        Count.Db.dbInsertWithCallback(table,toDbArray, me.loadStore, me);
      }
```

data stored on DB. But I need to validate ListName must be unique like a username. if there are any rerecords like the same name it should show an error. In this function were to check that validator or function? anyone have an idea please share

Answer (score 3):

You can find record with `ListName` using method [findRecord](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.data.AbstractStore.html#method-findRecord) on instance of `store`.

```
let record = store.findRecord('ListName', ListName, 0, false, false, true);

if (!record) {
    //do smth here if ListName not found
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. To where I have to add this function,
inside form or controller?

Comment: Hi @sarathi, first you need to load the store with your data from database and then in your form validate method, use findRecord to check if the "ListName" exists in your store. if you can not find then you can show error